# Ngx-datatable not shrinking when within flexbox with flex-direction: row

Tags: javascript, angular, flexbox, ngx-datatable

I place 2 block level elements within a container div with `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: row;`. The first element has a fixed with and doesn't shrink nor expanded to horizontal browser resize. The second element is an [Ngx-datatable](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/) which should shrink and expand on browser horizontal resize.

When I try to increase browser width, the table grows as expected. Problem arises when I try to reduce browser width. The table doesn't shrink and instead place overflowed contents on a scrollbar.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7c27.png

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vimhiq

My goal is to make the table responsize so that it would grow and shrink on browser resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.table-wrapper { 
   min-width: 0;
   ...
}
```

solves your problem.

Comment: It actually does but I'm not really sure why. Any idea why setting parent min-width forces the table to re-render on resize?